# PostgreSQL array_agg order

Tags: postgresql, array-agg

Table 'animals':

```
animal_name animal_type
Tom         Cat
Jerry       Mouse
Kermit      Frog
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
array_to_string(array_agg(animal_name),';') animal_names,
array_to_string(array_agg(animal_type),';') animal_types
FROM animals;
```

Expected result:

```
Tom;Jerry;Kerimt, Cat;Mouse;Frog
OR
Tom;Kerimt;Jerry, Cat;Frog;Mouse
```

Can I be sure that order in first aggregate function  will always be the same as in second.
I mean I would't like to get:

```
Tom;Jerry;Kermit, Frog;Mouse,Cat
```

Comment: If you are on 9.0 you can replace the nested calls with a single `string_agg()`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

*If you are on a PostgreSQL version < 9.0 then:*

From: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-aggregate.html

> In the current implementation, the order of the input is in principle unspecified. Supplying the input values from a sorted subquery will usually work, however. For example:
>
> SELECT xmlagg(x) FROM (SELECT x FROM test ORDER BY y DESC) AS tab;

So in your case you would write:

```
SELECT
array_to_string(array_agg(animal_name),';') animal_names,
array_to_string(array_agg(animal_type),';') animal_types
FROM (SELECT animal_name, animal_type FROM animals) AS x;
```

The input to the array_agg would then be unordered but it would be the same in both columns. And if you like you could add an `ORDER BY` clause to the subquery.

Answer (score 477):

Use an ORDER BY, like this example from the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES):

```
SELECT array_agg(a ORDER BY b DESC) FROM table;
```

Comment: Note: `ORDER BY` in `array_agg` is introduced in PostgreSQL 9

Comment: Much better than the accepted answer assuming PostgreSQL 9+.

Comment: Could you please give sample with ORDER BY for select: 

SELECT array_agg(animal_name), array_agg(animal_type) FROM animals;

?

Comment: I suppose SELECT 
  array_agg(name ORDER BY pk),
  array_agg(type ORDER BY pk)
FROM animal; is the answer by could it be simple?

Comment: Note that this does *not* work for `array_agg(DISTINCT a ORDER BY b)`

Comment: Surely arrays of different aggregations in a single SELECT are correlated, so specifying an explicit order is not required for the OP.

Comment: @cerd what do you suggest in case of DISTINCT? I want the a to be ordered

Comment: in that case you need to figure out what you want and explain it clearly. `DISTINCT a ORDER BY b` is unclear. eg: `(1,2),(2,1),(1,0)`

Comment: When using for multiple columns you have to add parentheses: `array_agg((a, b, c) ORDER BY b)`

Comment: This seems like a good place to mention the somewhat outlandish syntax for functions like `string_agg` which take multiple arguments: `SELECT string_agg(a, '|' ORDER BY b DESC)`

Comment: You saved my day!! I was going through various other solutions but I was looking for this! Thanks!

Comment: What if you're also using GROUP BY?

Comment: @Roelant Please post a new question with a complete example. The question above is from 2011, almost 13 years ago

Answer (score 8):

According to [Tom Lane](https://www.postgresql.org/community/contributors/):

> ... If I read it right, the OP wants to be sure that the two aggregate functions will see the data in the *same* unspecified order.  I think that's a pretty safe assumption.  The server would have to go way out of its way to do differently, and it doesn't.

> ... So it is documented behavior that an aggregate without its own ORDER BY will see the rows in whatever order the FROM clause supplies them.

So I think it's fine to assume that all the aggregates, none of which uses ORDER BY, in your query will see input data in the same order. The order itself is unspecified though (which depends on the order the FROM clause supplies rows).

Source: [PostgreSQL mailing list](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/592DF768-0FF1-4795-AAE9-B5B684A0469D%40gmail.com)

Comment: This is the only answer whose author actually bothered to understand the question, namely whether the *two aggregates* would have the *same* order.

Comment: I note that, in the linked mail thread, Tom Lane explicitly recommends *against* adding an `ORDER BY` statement to each `array_agg`, for efficiency reasons.

Answer (score 3):

Do this:

```
SELECT 
    array_to_string(array_agg(animal_name order by animal_name),';') animal_names,
    array_to_string(array_agg(animal_type order by animal_type),';') animal_types
FROM 
    animals;
```

Comment: ...but this results in different orders depending on the input.

Comment: This is not what OP is asking, he wants to order both the agg results to be consistent (animal_name1 correspondig to animal_type1)