# Unnest array by one level

Tags: arrays, postgresql, plpgsql

I want to take an array of `n` dimensions and return set containing rows of arrays of `n-1` dimensions. For example, take the array `ARRAY[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]` and return a set `{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}`. Using unnest returns the set `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`.

I tried grabbing the unnest function from PostgreSQL 8.4, which seems like it would do what I'm looking for:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tstng.unnest2(anyarray)
    RETURNS SETOF anyelement
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    IMMUTABLE
    AS $$
    BEGIN
            RETURN QUERY SELECT $1[i]
                FROM generate_series(array_lower($1,1), array_upper($1,1)) i;
        END;
    $$;
```

However, `SELECT tstng.unnest2(ARRAY[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]);` returns the set `, ,` (i.e.: 3 null rows).

I've also found that `SELECT (ARRAY[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])[0];` returns null, which I believe to be the root of my problem.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### Function

To break out 1-dimensional arrays from *n*-dimensional arrays - representing *leaves* of the nested dimensions. (With *n* >= 1.)

#### PL/pgSQL

With a [`FOR` loop](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY) looping through the array:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION unnest_nd_1d(a ANYARRAY, OUT a_1d ANYARRAY)
  RETURNS SETOF ANYARRAY
  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE STRICT AS
$func$
BEGIN
   FOREACH a_1d SLICE 1 IN ARRAY a LOOP
      RETURN NEXT;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

`SLICE 1` instructs to take the 1-dimensonal arrays. (`SLICE 2` would take 2-dimensional arrays.)

`PARALLEL SAFE` only for Postgres 9.6 or later.

Later tests revealed this PL/pgSQL function to be fastest.
Related:

- [How to unnest a 2d array into a 1d array quickly in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41402399/how-to-unnest-a-2d-array-into-a-1d-array-quickly-in-postgresql/41405177#41405177)

#### Pure SQL

Only works for 2D arrays:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION unnest_2d_1d(anyarray)
  RETURNS SETOF anyarray
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE STRICT AS
$func$
SELECT array_agg($1[d1][d2])
FROM   generate_subscripts($1,1) d1
    ,  generate_subscripts($1,2) d2
GROUP  BY d1
ORDER  BY d1
$func$;
```

This is an improved and simplified version of [the function Lukas posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9724943/939860).

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=9b7bcd0e8e27c1f64695f77b4beb167c)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c43058/1)</sub>

#### Explanation

```
SELECT (ARRAY[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])[0]
```

returns the same as:

```
SELECT (ARRAY[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])[17]
```

... which is `NULL`. [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html):

> By default, the lower bound index value of an array's dimensions is
> set to one.

`0` has no special meaning as array subscript. There's just nothing there for Postgres arrays with default indexes.
Also, with two-dimensional arrays, you need **two indexes** to get a base element. Like:

```
SELECT (ARRAY[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])[1][2]
```

Result:

```
2
```

The first part of your message is a bit unclear.

```
SELECT array_dims(ARRAY[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]);
```

Result:

```
[1:3][1:3]
```

That's **two** dimensions with 3 elements (1 to 3) each (9 base elements).
If you want `n-1` dimensions then this is a correct result:

```
SELECT ARRAY (SELECT unnest('{{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}}'::int[]))
```

Result:

```
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
```

That's **one** dimension. `unnest()` produces one base element per row (regardless of array dimensions). Your example is just another 2-dimensional array with a missing set of curly brackets ... ?

```
{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}
```

If you want a **slice of the array**:

```
SELECT (ARRAY[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])[1:2]
```

Result:

```
{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}
```

Or:

```
SELECT (ARRAY[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])[2:2][1:2]
```

Result:

```
{{4,5}}
```

To **flatten** the result (get a 1D array):

- [How to select 1d array from 2d array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25996237/how-to-select-1d-array-from-2d-array-postgresql/25997497#25997497)

[Read the manual here.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html)

### For very old versions

For Postgres versions < 8.4, `array_agg()` is not installed by default. Create it first:

```sql
CREATE AGGREGATE array_agg(anyelement) (
 SFUNC = array_append,
 STYPE = anyarray,
 INITCOND = '{}'
);
```

Also, [`generate_subscripts()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) is not born, yet. Use instead:

```
...
FROM   generate_series(array_lower($1,1), array_upper($1,1)) d1
    ,  generate_series(array_lower($1,2), array_upper($1,2)) d2
...
```

Call:

```
SELECT unnest_2d_1d(ARRAY[[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]);
```

Result

```
{1,2}
{3,4}
{5,6}
```

Comment: I was able to work from 0 having no special meaning, thank you.

Comment: When I run `SELECT (ARRAY[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])[1][2]` I get `2` not `1`. And `2` is exactly what I expected. Why `1`? Is it a mistake? Or am I missing something? Same with `SELECT (ARRAY[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])[2:2][3];` yielding `{{4,5,6}}`, not `{{4,5}}` (And by the way the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html) recommend using the full `[2:2][1:3]` notation to make it explicit too, and I agree!)

Comment: @poshest: Thanks, you are right in all points. Fixed the mistakes and updated the function, since this has become simpler since 2011.

Comment: Hi, in nowdays, with pg10, no news?  There are no build-in or efficient workaround to do unnest_2d_1d()?

Comment: I wish there was a function in Postgres that allows unnesting any n-dimensional array for 1 level. It's so annoying, that there is no easy way to do this.

Answer (score 10):

Slices of a multi-dimensional are returned as multi-dimensional arrays. This is a modified version of unnest that will take a 2-dimensional array and return a set of 1-dimensional arrays.

**update**: modified to use the built-in array_agg aggregate function that was default as of 8.4. (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-aggregate.html)

**Caveats:**

- It only works for 2-dimensional arrays (I should probably rename the function to reflect that limitation).
- If you are on 8.3 (and can't upgrade), you need to have the array_accum aggregate defined and change all references in the functions below from array_agg to array_accum. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/xaggr.html

**code:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION unnest_multidim(anyarray)
RETURNS SETOF anyarray AS
$BODY$
  SELECT array_agg($1[series2.i][series2.x]) FROM
    (SELECT generate_series(array_lower($1,2),array_upper($1,2)) as x, series1.i
     FROM 
     (SELECT generate_series(array_lower($1,1),array_upper($1,1)) as i) series1 
    ) series2
GROUP BY series2.i
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

**Result:**

```
select unnest_multidim(array[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]);
unnest_multidim
----------------------
{1,2,3}
{4,5,6}
{7,8,9}
(3 rows)
```

Now, let's say for some reason you want easy access to just one of these arrays that is returned. The following function adds an optional index parameter that will return the nested array of the index you provide, or, if you provide null, will output the full set of "unnested" arrays.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION unnest_multidim(anyarray, integer)
  RETURNS SETOF anyarray AS
$BODY$
SELECT array_agg($1[series2.i][series2.x]) FROM
  (SELECT generate_series(array_lower($1,2),array_upper($1,2)) as x, series1.i
  FROM 
    (SELECT CASE WHEN $2  IS NULL THEN
      generate_series(array_lower($1,1),array_upper($1,1)) 
      ELSE $2
      END as i) series1
  ) series2
GROUP BY series2.i
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

**Results:**

```
db=> select unnest_multidim(array[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],2);
 unnest_multidim 
-----------------
 {4,5,6}
(1 row)

db=> select unnest_multidim(array[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],NULL);
 unnest_multidim 
-----------------
 {1,2,3}
 {4,5,6}
 {7,8,9}
(3 rows)
```

Comment: [PotsgreSQL 8.4 introduced `array_agg()` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-aggregate.html) that is the standard name for `array_accum`.

Answer (score 0):

A word of caution: when using array_agg on postgres <9 order may change 
[PostgreSQL array_agg order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317475/postgresql-array-agg-order)
If you plan to use the unnested array say for finding argmax, this will corrupt your data.