# Postgresql: dynamic slice notation for arrays

Tags: arrays, postgresql

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137112/unnest-array-by-one-level/9724943#8142998) I wrote a naive attempt to produce this

```
col1
---------
1
4
7
```

from this

`ARRAY[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]`

This works

`SELECT unnest((ARRAY[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])[1:3][1:1]);`

But I in my case, I don't know the length of the outer array.

So is there a way to hack together the slice "string" to take into account this variability?

Here was my attempt. I know, it's a bit funny

`_ids := _ids_2D[('1:' || array_length(_ids_2D, 1)::text)::int][1:1];`

As you can see, I just want to create the effect of `[1:n]`.  Obviously `'1:3'` ain't going to parse nicely into what the array slice needs.

I could obviously use something like the `unnest_2d_1d` Erwin mentions in the answer linked above, but hoping for something more elegant.

Comment: Do you want an array with the first element of all nested (2nd level) of an array (1st level)?

Comment: I am not sure if the array_length would not work, because the 1:n is a string anyway. Need to check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are trying to get the first element of all nested (2nd dimension) arrays inside an array (1st dimension) then you may use

```
array_upper(anyarray, 1)
```

to get all elements of a specific dimension

```
anyarray[1:array_upper(anyarray, 1)][<dimension num>:<dimension num>]
```

e.g, to get all elements of the first dimension

```
anyarray[1:array_upper(anyarray, 1)][1:1]
```

as in the code above. Please refer to PostgreSQL manual section on [Arrays](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/arrays.html) for more information.

Comment: Great stuff Inrdo!  `array_length` that I was using would also work. But it was trying to make a string first that caused my problem.