# Compare an array to elements of a multi-dimensional array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, multidimensional-array

I have a table in a PostgreSQL 9.6 database:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table (
 column_name varchar(255)[],
 name        varchar(40)
);

INSERT INTO new_table VALUES
 ('{one, two}'  , 'first_user'),
 ('{other, two}', 'second_user'),
 ('{one, more}' , 'third_user');
```

I have an array of arrays (2D-array) and want to find all rows of the table where `column_name` matches any of the contained 1D-array. I'm after something like this:

```
select * 
from new_table as s
where s.column_name = any('{{"one", "two"}, {"one", "more"}, {"two", "five"}}')
```

But this gives me the error:

> ```
> ERROR:  could not find array type for data type text[]
> ```

My desired result:

```
column_name |    name
------------+--------------
{one,two}   | first_user
{one,more}  | third_user
```

Any one has any idea?

Comment: If you want to compare (ie query the data), it means you shouldn't be using an array in the first place. You should create a one-to-many table to hold the different values you want for each user

Comment: Why not disclose your Postgres version? Should go without saying ...

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos How do you mean I shouldn't be using a array, in the table or the array of arrays? At the moment I loop  through the array and compare the array with `'{"one", "two"}' = s.column_name` instead, I was just curious I it was possible to do it i one call instead of a lot of calls to the db.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter oh forgot that, has edit the post now.

Answer (score 0):

use array operator for work with operators:

```
t=# select *
from new_table as s
where s.column_name <@ '{{"one", "two"}, {"one", "more"}, {"two", "five"}}';
 column_name |    name
-------------+------------
 {one,two}   | first_user
 {one,more}  | third_user
(2 rows)
```

I assume https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#idm46428706346880 could have some notes, that *expression* is not array and you can't use it for such comparison

**update**

to be able to "unnest array by 1 dimention" and use the result set for `in`comarison, use [Pavel Stěhule](https://stackoverflow.com/users/406691/pavel-stehule) suggested [function](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAFj8pRD3DrqCa68NjHUcC8%3DyT1%3D7XvtYkxUMYFuuDuboixDcjw@mail.gmail.com):

```
t=# select * from new_table 
where column_name in (
  select reduce_dim('{{one, two}, {two, more}, {one, five}}'::character varying[])
);
 column_name |    name
-------------+------------
 {one,two}   | first_user
(1 row)
```

Comment: Yes this almost works, but I need a method that compare that two arrays are equal, if I use <@ this array `'{{"one", "two"}, {"two", "more"}, {"one", "five"}}'` will give the same result and in my case I need it to only give one result since `{"one", "more"}` isn't in it.

Comment: @Elmseld I included the slicing array fn(), but there's already Erwins answer ready :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Error message

For the record, your superficial error:

> ```
> ERROR:  could not find array type for data type text[]
> ```

.. would go away with an explicit cast. Like:

```
...
WHERE column_name = any('{{"one", "two"}, {"one", "more"}, {"two", "five"}}'::varchar[])
```

But that would *not* solve the underlying problem:

> ```
> ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying[] = character varying
> ```

#### Explanation

Postgres support for multi-dimensional arrays can be confusing. In fact, `varchar(255)[]` resolves to the exact same data type as `varchar(255)[][]` internally.

- [mapping postgresql text[][] type and Java type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743841/mapping-postgresql-text-type-and-java-type/10745524#10745524)

The ***element*** type of each of these array values is `varchar` (not `varchar[]`). The `ANY` construct effectively ignores array dimensions. 
[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html)

> Array comparisons compare the array contents element-by-element

#### Solution

To achieve what you want, you need to unnest 2D-arrays to 1D-arrays. Create this function *once* per database:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION unnest_2d_1d(ANYARRAY, OUT a ANYARRAY)
  RETURNS SETOF ANYARRAY AS
$func$
BEGIN
   FOREACH a SLICE 1 IN ARRAY $1 LOOP
      RETURN NEXT;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

Further reading:

- [How to unnest a 2d array into a 1d array quickly in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41402399/how-to-unnest-a-2d-array-into-a-1d-array-quickly-in-postgresql/41405177#41405177)
- [Unnest array by one level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137112/unnest-array-by-one-level/8142998#8142998)

Now, all of these queries work:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM   unnest_2d_1d('{{"one", "two"}, {"one", "more"}, {"two", "five"}}'::varchar[]) a(column_name)
JOIN   new_table t USING (column_name);
```

Or:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM   new_table t
WHERE  column_name = ANY ((SELECT unnest_2d_1d('{{"one", "two"}, {"one", "more"}, {"two", "five"}}'::varchar[])));
```

Or:

```
...
WHERE  column_name IN ((SELECT unnest_2d_1d('{{"one", "two"}, {"one", "more"}, {"two", "five"}}'::varchar[])));
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=8f5df36321821ca4ed7e55c732f4bf97)*

Related:

- [How to use ANY instead of IN in a WHERE clause with Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31191507/how-to-use-any-instead-of-in-in-a-where-clause-with-rails/31192557#31192557)

#### Asides

This is one of the rare cases where a btree index on an array column might be useful:

```
CREATE INDEX ON new_table(column_name);
```

There is nothing special about `varchar(255)` in Postgres. I mostly just use `text`. See:

- [What is the overhead for varchar(n)?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/125499/what-is-the-overhead-for-varcharn/125526#125526)
- [Indexes: integer vs string performance if the number of nodes is the same](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/137945/indexes-integer-vs-string-performance-if-the-number-of-nodes-is-the-same/137949#137949)
- [Do fixed-width rows improve PostgreSQL read performance?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/113149/do-fixed-width-rows-improve-postgresql-read-performance/113162#113162)