# Postgres unnest ignores array of arrays structure

Tags: arrays, postgresql

These two Postgres function calls return the same, whereas I would expect the latter to retain its nested array structure. How do I do that?

```
SELECT * FROM unnest('{1, 10, 100, 2, 11, 101}'::integer[]);

SELECT * FROM unnest('{{1, 10, 100}, {2, 11, 101}}'::integer[]);
```

I need this for manipulating array of arrays.

Comment: For anyone curious, solving this subproblem is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57263338/continuously-insert-all-unique-combinations-encountered-of-three-ids

Answer (score 2):

There is a wiki page about this.
https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Unnest_multidimensional_array

Besides, PostgreSQL has much more functions for JSON than arrays.

```
SELECT * FROM jsonb_array_elements(to_jsonb('{{1, 10, 100}, {2, 11, 101}}'::integer[]));
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks great. How does it compare in speed with @S-Man's answer?

Answer (score 1):

Using this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8142998/3984221 from @LukasEklund and @ErwinBrandstetter

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=aa3d087fc7f26ea368f1513aa8a8d7e5)

```
SELECT array_agg(t.myarray[d1][d2])
FROM   mytable t,
       generate_subscripts(t.myarray,1) d1,
       generate_subscripts(t.myarray,2) d2
GROUP  BY d1
ORDER  BY d1
```

[`generate_subscript()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) generates a consecutive number list from 1 to the dimension size given by the second parameter.

Comment: Thanks! This looks great. How does it compare in speed with @crvv's answer?

Comment: The solution of crvv seems to be much faster (in this case, I am curious about real data) but does not give out an simple array but a json array. Comparison of speed (have a look at the costs) and output: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=f9cd965d71ffac4944aa26aef2d5af85