# psql bluk insert array column with different length

Tags: psql, bulkinsert, unnest, asyncpg

The `unnest` work fine for no array data.
I want to bluk insert an array column. My input like this: `[[1, 2], [1]]`

```
create table test_array
(
    arr int[],
    info text[]
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION unnest_2d_1d(anyarray)
RETURNS SETOF anyarray AS
$func$
SELECT array_agg($1[d1][d2])
FROM   generate_subscripts($1,1) d1
    ,  generate_subscripts($1,2) d2
GROUP  BY d1
ORDER  BY d1
$func$  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;

insert into test_array(
arr)
values (
unnest_2d_1d(array[[1,2], [3,4]]::int[]));  -- work fine


insert into test_array(
arr)
values (
unnest_2d_1d(array[[1,2], [3]]::int[]));   -- will failed
```

The failed error is :

```
 ERROR: multidimensional arrays must have array expressions with matching dimensions
```

`unnest_2d_1d` come from [Unnest array by one level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137112/unnest-array-by-one-level/8142998#8142998)
While all such function can't support different length of array.

Another same error happened with array_dims:

```
postgres=# SELECT array_dims(ARRAY[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8]])
postgres-# ;
ERROR:  multidimensional arrays must have array expressions with matching dimensions
```

What I need to do with `unnest_2d_1d` to make the failed one can be success?

Why I must do with unnest. Because `asyncpg` `execute_many` discard the returning values. So I need use one sql to insert data. But the array column is such like one dim with different length.

**---- add some python and asyncpg**

I find a github issue related this problem,  https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/1644 try to do with python

When try this :

```
async def h():
    async with misc.pg_pool.acquire() as connection:
        stmt = await connection.prepare(f"""
            insert into test_array(info)  select (info::text[]) from  unnest($1::text[])
            AS t(info)
        """)
        await stmt.fetch([["sd", "dg"]])
```

got this

```
InvalidTextRepresentationError: malformed array literal: "sd"
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.

This will work:

```
insert into test_array(info) 
        select (info::text[]) from  unnest(array['{"sd", "dg"}', '{"g"}']::text[]) as t(info)
```

This will work too:

```
insert into test_array(info) 
        select info from jsonb_to_recordset('[{"info":["ttt"]}, {"info":["tt","t"]}]'::jsonb) as t(info text[])
```