Bulk insert into a postgres table that has an array column with parameterized query
I have the following table:
┌────────────────┬─────────────────────────────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│     Column     │            Type             │ Collation │ Nullable │                             Default                              │
├────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ id             │ bigint                      │           │ not null │ nextval('"HistoricalDataAggregatorWorkOrders_id_seq"'::regclass) ││
│ inputTimeRange │ tstzrange                   │           │ not null │                                                                  │
│ outputTags     │ tag[]                       │           │ not null │                                                                  │
└────────────────┴─────────────────────────────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

I want to bulk insert a bunch of rows into it in one parameterized query.  I thought I'd be able to do it the usual way with unnest:
INSERT INTO "HistoricalDataAggregatorWorkOrders"
  ("inputTimeRange", "outputTags")
  SELECT * from unnest($1::tstzrange[], $2::tag[][])
  RETURNING id;

But unfortunately, unnest doesn't work the way I want (it flattens the array).
I gather from https://stackoverflow.com/a/8142998/200224 that there's no builtin unnest-one-level function.
Is there really no simple way to bulk insert with a parameterized query when one column is an array type?  Seems like a missing feature...

Most postgresql adaptors have a bulk-insert operation. I don't know about whatever you are using

Slowest to quickest, you can run bulk inserts by: 1) running multiple single-row inserts, 2) one huge insert...values or 3) a copy. You're between 1 and 2, trying to send a single row, that you then want to split on the db-end with an SRF. I'd either try and bind these arrays as lists of values client-side to sidestep the problem of how SQL arrays behave, or try to upgrade that to a copy. The array method does look pretty intuitive and will get you there most of the way, most of the time, but I don't think that's how it's commonly implemented.

How to do a bulk insert with node-postgres, Multi-row insert with pg-promise.

@RichardHuxton I'm using Sequelize 6, it does have a bulk insert operation but it has bugs with tstzrange and array-valued columns in bulk inserts.

@Zegarek in this case my primary goal isn't performance.  Unfortunately, because Sequelize is heavily integrated into our codebase, and because my boss is wary of using a centralized connection pool like pgBouncer, I have to do as much as possible through Sequelize's connection pool to keep our connection counts down.

@Andy 2 and 3 both use a single transaction, session, connection - I would only be worried about a spike in connections if you tried to do the opposite and downgrade to 1, pushing everything in separate inserts. Changing the way you do 2 or upgrading to 3 would let you avoid the array problem and the improved performance is a secondary effect you get for free.

@Zegarek it seems like you're saying my unnest approach inserts a single row into the table? but it can insert an arbitrary number of rows.  I didn't understand what you meant by "you're between 1 and 2", are you saying there's somehow more of a performance penalty to using unnest than using a values list?  Naively I would assume they perform about the same, since each is a single query and roughly the same amount of data is sent over the wire.

I might consider using copy if I could find a library for pg formatting that I trust and can use.  I've preferred the unnest approach for cases where I can avoid doing any formatting outside of node-pg.  pg-promise seems good at formatting but seems like it would have to go through a node-pg connection pool...unfortunately I have to go through Sequelize's connection pool.

@Andy I'm not saying you insert a single value, only that you send a one to be split into multiple - not having to do that unnest might be slightly faster but most importantly, less complicated and free from having to deal with the SQL array behaviour. From your responses I gather you're aware the clean method you ask about is the sequelize bulkCreate, or the standard pg-promise multi-row insert - both of which form the standard insert..values Richard and I referred to. But since one's bugged and you're restricted from using the other, either of the workarounds below should do.

It might be worth attaching a link to the github issue with bulkCreate that prevents you from passing the tstzranges and arrays the standard way. If there isn't one and you meant that it just doesn't work like you expect it to, it might be a good idea to open a thread to dig into that - maybe you could get that working the normal way, without the need for more or less unclean workarounds.

I hadn't created the issues yet.  Turns out that normally Sequelize handles text[] and tstzrange just fine, but the issue seems to be that outputTags is an array of my custom domain tag (just text with a check constraint) and I have registered a custom DateWithMicroseconds type with pg-types that seemed to have issues when I was trying use tstzrange[] for something else.

In any case, even if I did bulkCreate with Sequelize, I also want to do a bulk update in a single statement which isn't possible with Sequelize (different column values for each id to update), and for that I have to do something similar to this question.

If the lengths of both arrays are designed to match, you can unpack just one, requesting each element to also present its index (with ordinality clause), then use that to address elements in the other array.
demo at db<>fiddle
PREPARE myinsert(tstzrange[],tag[][]) AS
INSERT INTO "HistoricalDataAggregatorWorkOrders"
  ("inputTimeRange", "outputTags")
SELECT "inputTimeRange"
      ,array(select unnest(($2::tag[][])[i:i]))
FROM unnest($1::tstzrange[]) with ordinality as u("inputTimeRange",i)
RETURNING id;

Since SQL arrays can only return either individual elements or whole slices of equal dimensionality as the whole input array (not arrays of N-K dimension when you skip K subscripts), array(select unnest(<slice>) has to peel that one dimension away - otherwise you'd get a "nested" 2D {{(abc),(def)}} instead of a 1D {(abc),(def)} you want.
execute myinsert( '{ "[2024-05-05T01:00,2024-05-05T02:00]"
                    ,"[2024-05-05T03:00,2024-05-05T04:00]"}'
                 ,'{ {"(abc)","(def)"}
                    ,{"(ghi)","(jkl)"} }');




id
inputTimeRange
outputTags




1
["2024-05-05 01:00:00+01","2024-05-05 02:00:00+01"]
{(abc),(def)}


2
["2024-05-05 03:00:00+01","2024-05-05 04:00:00+01"]
{(ghi),(jkl)}



The two unnest calls should perform comparably to the single call for two arrays at once but the null-padding will only work one way, for larger/longer $1, compared to the single multi-array unnest:

If the arrays are not all the same length then the shorter ones are padded with NULLs.

Except for the fact it saves your from switching to jsonb and back or going through the text[]::tag[] casts, it's still not much cleaner than what you had already.

I don't love it but I went with a jsonb[] parameter:
INSERT INTO "HistoricalDataAggregatorWorkOrders"
  ("inputTimeRange", "outputTags")
  SELECT (o->>'inputTimeRange')::tstzrange, (o->>'outputTags')::tag[]
    FROM unnest($1::jsonb[]) u(o)
  RETURNING id;

Update: realized I could unnest a text[] and then cast an element of that to ::tag[]:
INSERT INTO "HistoricalDataAggregatorWorkOrders"
  ("inputTimeRange", "outputTags")
  SELECT "inputTimeRange", "outputTags"::tag[]
    FROM unnest($1::tstzrange[], $2::text[])
      u("inputTimeRange", "outputTags")
  RETURNING *;

It still doesn't feel that clean...if there isn't a cleaner way to do this with builtin features, then a way should be added...
Ideally I'd like a way to leave serialization of the parameters  completely up to the db driver (node-pg, which may have limitations.)
If anyone knows a more elegant way to do it, let me know.
