# Sorting in array_agg function

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.1

I have a query shown below

```
SELECT 
  league.country as id, 
  array_agg(DISTINCT row(league.id, league.name::varchar)) AS league_names, 

FROM league 
GROUP BY league.country
```

How can I sort by league.name::varchar in array_agg function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL array\_agg order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317475/postgresql-array-agg-order)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Aggregates accept an `ORDER BY`. So you can write:

```
array_agg(thecol ORDER BY someothercol)
```

e.g.

```
array_agg(
  DISTINCT 
  row(league.id, league.name::varchar) 
  ORDER BY league.name
) AS league_names,
```