# PostgreSQL array_agg order for window functions

Tags: postgresql, array-agg

The answer to my question was almost here: [PostgreSQL array_agg order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317475/postgresql-array-agg-order)

Except that I wanted to array_agg over a window function:

```
 select distinct c.concept_name, 
        array_agg(c2.vocabulary_id||':'||c2.concept_name 
                  order by c2.vocabulary_id, c2.concept_name) 
            over (partition by ca.min_levels_of_separation), 
        ca.min_levels_of_separation
 from concept c
 join concept_ancestor ca on c.concept_id = ca.descendant_concept_id 
      and max_levels_of_separation > 0
 join concept c2 on ca.ancestor_concept_id = c2.concept_id 
 where 
 c.concept_code = '44054006'
 order by min_levels_of_separation;
```

So, maybe this will work in some future version, but I get this error

```
 ERROR:  aggregate ORDER BY is not implemented for window functions
 LINE 2: select distinct c.concept_name, array_agg(c2.vocabulary_id||...
                                    ^
```

I should probably be selecting from a subquery like the first answer to the quoted question above suggests. I was hoping for something as simple as the order by (in that question's second answer). Or maybe I'm just being lazy about the query and should be doing a `group by` instead of `select distinct`.

I did try putting the order by in the windowing function (`over (partition by ca.min_levels_of_separation order by c2.vocabulary_id, c2.concept_name)`), but I get these sort of repeated rows that way:

```
 "Type 2 diabetes mellitus";"{"MedDRA:Diabetes mellitus"}";1
 "Type 2 diabetes mellitus";"{"MedDRA:Diabetes mellitus","MedDRA:Diabetes mellitus (incl subtypes)"}";1
 "Type 2 diabetes mellitus";"{"MedDRA:Diabetes mellitus","MedDRA:Diabetes mellitus (incl subtypes)","SNOMED:Diabetes mellitus"}";1
```

(btw: http://www.ohdsi.org/ if you happen to be curious about where I got the medical vocabulary tables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does look like I was being muddle-headed and didn't need the window function. This seems to work:

```
 select  c.concept_name, 
         array_agg(c2.vocabulary_id||':'||c2.concept_name 
                   order by c2.vocabulary_id, c2.concept_name), 
         ca.min_levels_of_separation
 from concept c
 join concept_ancestor ca on c.concept_id = ca.descendant_concept_id 
      and max_levels_of_separation > 0
 join concept c2 on ca.ancestor_concept_id = c2.concept_id
 where c.concept_code = '44054006'
 group by c.concept_name, ca.min_levels_of_separation
 order by min_levels_of_separation
```

I won't accept my answer for a while since it just avoids the question instead of actually answering it, and someone might have something more useful to say on the matter.

Comment: Looks totally fine at a quick glance

Answer (score 0):

like this :

```
select distinct c.concept_name, 
    array_agg(c2.vocabulary_id||':'||c2.concept_name ) over (partition by ca.min_levels_of_separation  order by c2.vocabulary_id, c2.concept_name), 
    ca.min_levels_of_separation
from concept c
join concept_ancestor ca on c.concept_id = ca.descendant_concept_id 
  and max_levels_of_separation > 0
join concept c2 on ca.ancestor_concept_id = c2.concept_id 
where 
c.concept_code = '44054006'
order by min_levels_of_separation;
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have said I tried that. It gives me sort of repeated rows. I'll edit the question to show what I mean (can't format it in a comment.)