# How to aggregate specific rows in a column into arrays?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, aggregate

I have table such as

```
| work_order_id | part_number | due_date   |
|: 1            |:P123:       | 2022-03-04:|
|: 2            |:P123:       | 2022-03-11:|
|: 3            |:P123:       | 2022-04-02:|
```

Essentially I wanted to create a view where the first and third rows are aggregated by the order of the second column. So the resulting view should look like:

```
|: {1,2,3}|:P123:| {2022-04-2, 2022-03-11, 2022-04-2:|
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate of:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317475/postgresql-array-agg-order

Answer (score 0):

The Aggregrate function ARRAY_AGG() seems to be what you're after.

```
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(work_order_ID ORDER BY work_order_ID) as WorkorderIDs
     , part_number
     , ARRAY_AGG(due_Date ORDER BY work_order_ID) as due_dates
FROM yourTableName
GROUP BY part_number
```

- [TechDocs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-aggregate.html)
- [Other Examples](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-aggregate-functions/postgresql-array_agg-function/)